# Template variable assignment segment fault 11

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, hashtable, singly-linked-list

I am currently working on a hash table project for school and i have run into an issue that i cant figure out. My professor provided us with classes that have functions that we need to implement and these functions make use of templates.

Anyway, in my insert function, i am running into an issue with setting a value of a node in the singly-linked list structure i am using to implement the hash table.

My problem is this:

```
void insert(U item1, U item2){  //For my project U is a string
    Node<U>* temp = headPtr;

    cout << item1 << endl; //Will print out the string no problem

    //Assignment attempt
    temp->SSN = item1; // causes a seg fault


    temp->name = item2;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(headPtr->next == NULL){
        headPtr->next = temp;
        size++;
    }
    else{
        Node<U>* temp2 = headPtr;
        while(temp2->next != NULL){
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        temp2->next = temp;
        size++;
    }
}
```

And it is quite frustrating because in previous assignments i have been able to use this insert function properly, the only reason it does not work i have concluded is because i must be missing something with templates that i have overlooked.

Also here is my node.h file:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using  namespace  std;

 template <class T>
 struct  Node{
 T SSN;
 T name;
 Node<T>*  next;
 };
```

I am trying to assign a string value to what SHOULD be a string value and should work to as far as my understanding goes but every time i run the program it gets to this point and there is just segment fault 11.

Comment: Is headPtr declared as `Node<U>*` and contains a result of calling `new Node<U>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace

```
  Node<U>* temp = headPtr;
```

with

```
  Node<U>* temp = new Node<U>;
```

Comment: That did it, thank you. It makes sense, the node that i was referring to was NULL so it couldnt have values there.